# Using money-rails: How to manually set an attribute's currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, money-rails

I'm currently using:

- money-rails `v0.12.0`
- rails `v4.1.6`
- ruby `v2.1.3`

**Use case**

I'm updating a money type attribute called `dollars_per_month`, which I created with the `money-rails` migration helpers (i.e `add_money`).

So, in my model I have:

```
monetize :dollars_per_month_cents, allow_nil: true
```

And my current schema has:

```
t.integer  "dollars_per_month_cents"
t.string   "dollars_per_month_currency", default: "CAD", null: false
```

Currency is set globally in config/initializers:

```
config.default_currency = :cad
```

**Question**

I want the user to be able to enter "500 USD" OR "500" OR "500 CAD" in a text field, and have it save properly. Currently, when a non-global currency is specified, it throws the exception:

```
RuntimeError: Can't change readonly currency 'CAD' to 'USD' for field 'dollars_per_month'
```

Which makes sense- I can understand why this is naturally enforced.

However.. I want to forcibly change the currency *without* caring about such enforcements because this field is merely there for capturing the answer to a question.

The simple solution (despite the future lack of convenience) is to turn this into plain text. However, I am wondering if it is possible to do this with RubyMoney and/or money-rails without touching the rest of the app.

**Notes**

- I've tried changing `dollars_per_month_currency` and saving the model, however, `dollars_per_month` still returns a CAD based Money object.
- I've looked into Instance Currencies in the money-rails [readme](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#instance-currencies). While I believe I could make this work, I feel it is overkill because it requires extra currency fields.. when I just want to change `dollars_per_month_currency`.

Appreciate any insights or experience anyone has to share!

Answer (score 2):

Use the option *with_model_currency*:

```
monetize :dollars_per_month_cents, allow_nil: true, with_model_currency: :dollar_per_month_currency
```